# How to update/replace an ol.Map layers Array by another Array and with that changing the order of the layers in the map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-ui, openlayers-3

```js
  var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [layer0,layer1,layer2,layer3,layer4,layer5,layer6], 
  
  target: 'map',
  
        view: view
 });
 
 
 $('#lagenlijst').sortable({
        
        update: function(event, ui) {   
           var lagenlijstvolgorde = $(this).sortable('toArray');      
      
   map.layers = [].concat(lagenlijstvolgorde);
     
   console.log(map.layers); // show the id's from the html ol
   
   map.renderSync(); // to redraw the map
  } 
 });
```

```html
<div id="layertree" class="tree">
 
      <h4>Click on the names of the map layers for the visibility, legend and explanation.</h4>
      <ol  id="layerlist"   class="example">  
           
  
  <li id="layer0"><span>Openstreetmaps</span> 
  
          <fieldset id="layer0">
            <label class="checkbox" for="visible0">
              <input id="visible0" class="visible" type="checkbox" />      
     zichtbaarheid
            </label>
            <label>transparantie</label>
            <input class="opacity" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01"/>
   <a href="data/explanations/expalnation1.htm"onclick="window.open('data/explanations/exampltext_explanation.htm','Explanation', 
    'width=300,height=325,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,location=no'); return false">Explanation on a map</a> 
          </fieldset>
       
        </li>  
  
  <li id="layer1"><span>Worldmap</span>
   <!-- etc.-->
  </li>
  
  <!-- etc.-->
</ol>
    </div>
```

I have an HTML list (ol) as the Layertree for the order of the map layers and other features such as transparency, visibility and links to legends and explanations on the map layers.

Each li element has an unique id  for each layer in the map (layer0,layer1,layer2, etc.).

In the Javascript/OpenLayers code an ol.Map Array determines the order of the layers in the map with the same id’s [layer0,layer1,layer2, etc.].

With the sortable widget method ‘toArray’ from jQueryUI (http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray)  the HTML list/layertree is made sortable and this sorting works.

As intended it also creates an Array of the id’s from the HTML ol/layertree in the current order of the layertree and it adjusts if the user changes the order of the layertree with drag and drop (as a control the Array is made visible in console.log).

However, I do not manage to let the ol.Map Array follow/adjust to the order of layers id’s in the HTML list/layertree when the user changes the order of the layertree and so also adjusting the order of the layers in the map.

I have been trying for more than a week but unfortunately without any working result.

I hope that this text and the added pieces of code will clarify the core of the problem and somebody can show me the way how to solve this.